# How to split string in android?

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I'm retrieving a string of Textview from Online which has following structure.

This line is before special Character | This line is  after special character

I'm looking to add Two Textview in Mainactivity. First Textview will show 
the first Line before and "|" and Second Textview will show the Text after "|".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Split the line in 2 with the `split()` method, using the special character `|` as separator/delimeter, which will return an array of the 2 strings:

```
String[] splitted = line.split("\\|");
textView1.setText(splitted[0]);
textView1.setText(splitted[1]);
```

`line` is the original string
or by using `substring()`:

```
textView1.setText(line.substring(0, line.indexOf("|")));
textView1.setText(line.substring(line.indexOf("|") + 1));
```

Comment: Okay the second  solution works..but what if I have 2 "|" and I want to have three textview with One first line before "|", and one textview with in between "|" and one textview containint text after "|"..any solution?

Comment: @BirNepali The 1st solution works too, unless the the special character is not `|` and it does not need escaping like `"\\|"` and this the method to use if you have 3 or more textviews. The line will be split to more than 2 parts which you can get by `splitted[0]`, `splitted[1]`, `splitted[2]`,....

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
yourTextView.setText("| " + textYouWantToAdd)
```

and

```
yourTextView.setText(textYouWantToAdd " |" +)
```